# Awk Array Loop translation

Tags: loops, awk, hp-ux

While working on a HP UX storage migration project,
I found an `awk` statement as following

```
ioscan -funNCdisk | \
awk '{a[NR]=$0} $0~s {f[NR]++} END {for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) if (f[j]) for (i=j+C;i<=j+C;i++) \
print a[i]}' C=1 s="NetApp"
```

It appears it prints out the lines that match "NetApp" and some more lines related to that keyword.

Could anyone help me understand what this statement means?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to learn `awk`, there are some useful links: http://polymer.bu.edu/~fding/sedawk/index.htm   http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html    http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_toc.html

Answer (score 2):

Let's break out that `awk` script into a file by itself and call that file `script.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN   { C = 1; s = "pants" }
        { a[NR] = $0 }
$0 ~ s  { f[NR]++ }
END     {
    for (j = 1; j <= NR; j++)
        if (f[j])
            for (i = j + C; i <= j + C; i++)
                print a[i]
}
```

1. I added the initialization of the variables `s` and `C` in a `BEGIN` block, just for my own convenience while testing. Your script takes these from the command line.
2. Add current line last in array `a`.
3. If the line contains the string `s` (tested as regular expression), increment array `f` at index
    corresponding to current line (this is the same as `f[NR] = 1` in this case).
4. At end of input: Loop through all stored lines, and if we've flagged the line in the `f` array print the stored lines, starting at the flagged line plus `C` and continuing to, uhh, no, just print that single line (bug here?).

Our script will therefore print every line that comes after any line matching the regular expression `s`.

Testing it:

```
$ cat data.in
Hello world!
My pants
are on fire!
No, hold on,
Those are not *my* pants.
Phew!

$ chmod +x script.awk

$ ./script.awk data.in
are on fire!
Phew!
```

So, in your case (replace "pants" with "NetApp" here), it's virtually identical to (using GNU `sed`)

```
sed -n '/pants/,+1p' data.in | grep -v 'pants'
```

or

```
grep -A1 'pants' data.in | grep -E -v 'pants|-'
```

**Personal note**: This is why I *hate* so-called "one-liners". They are ugly, nobody understands them, and they are totally unmaintainable.  Please, *please*, put complex tasks in a scripts, write it cleanly and with comments, and use *that* as your "one-liner".

**EDIT**: After some thinking, I realized that thise script *probably* tries to implement `grep -Cnum re` for `num = C` and `re = s` (to get `C` lines of context), but it gets the loop indices wrong in the inner loop (should be `i = j - C; i <= j + C`).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kusalananda:) Now my curiosity is get released!
You're right the range for this loop was originally designed to be from j-c to j+c but somehow modified, probably someone intended to just find one row, not several rows.